# Object doesn't support this action at _ActivatedRoute_58

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Am using unit testing in Angular 2 by using Jasmin and Karma.

I need mock this below code

```
this.activatedRoute.url.subscribe(url => {
            debugger;
            this.isEdit = false;
            if (url[0].path === 'updatecoc') {
                this.isEdit = true;
            }
        });
```

I have tried mocking by this way : 
[How to mock an activatedRoute parent Route in angular2 for testing purposes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40790202/2218635)

```
let fakeActivatedRoute = new MockActivatedRoute();
    fakeActivatedRoute.parent = new MockActivatedRoute();

    let urlSegment: UrlSegment[] = [];
    urlSegment.push({ path: "updatecoc", parameters: {} });
    fakeActivatedRoute.url = Observable.of(urlSegment);    
    beforeEach(() => {    
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({

            imports: [FormsModule, MessagesModule, DataTableModule, DropdownModule, ConfirmDialogModule, AccordionModule,
                AutoCompleteModule, DialogModule, EditorModule, HttpModule],
            declarations: [MaintainCOCComponent],
            providers: [{ provide: MaintainCOCService, useClass: MaintainCOCService },
            { provide: Configuration, useClass: Configuration },
            { provide: Router, useClass: MockRouter },
            { provide: ActivatedRoute, useClass: fakeActivatedRoute }];
```

But am getting an error while mocking `ActivatedRoute` Module. I have tried everything from 2 days. I can't resolve this issue.

The full error message is:

```
Object doesn't support this action
   at _ActivatedRoute_58.get (Function code:173:46)
   at DynamicTestModuleInjector.prototype.getInternal (Function code:281:43)
   at NgModuleInjector.prototype.get (http://localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts:60528:9)
   at TestBed.prototype.get (http://localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts:17440:13)
   at AppView.prototype.injectorGet (http://localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts:89000:17)
   at DebugAppView.prototype.injectorGet (http://localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts:89428:13)
   at View_MaintainCOCComponent_Host0.prototype.createInternal (Function code:20:3)
   at AppView.prototype.createHostView (http://localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts:88956:9)
   at DebugAppView.prototype.createHostView (http://localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts:89412:13)
   at ComponentFactory.prototype.create (http://localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts:44498:9)
```

**Note:** I should provide a bounty for resolved answer.

Comment: `fakeActivatedRoute ` is not a function so what you are doing makes no sense. You can use `useValue` or `useFactory` to inject an existing object.

Comment: @AluanHaddad could you please provide it as an answer? fakeActivatedRoute  is an instance of a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because you are an registering an existing object using the `useClass` provider option.

When the injector resolves the `ActivatedRoute` dependency, it sees that the registered provider has a `useClass` property and attempts to instantiate that property's value as a constructor.

Since you have an existing value `fakeActivatedRoute` you can register it using the `useValue` property instead

```
providers: [{provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: fakeActivatedRoute}]
```

Alternately, you can register the MockActivatedRoute constructor, instead of creating an instance

```
providers: [{provide: ActivatedRoute, useClass: MockActivatedRoute}]
```

Additionally, your registration code can and should be simplified from

```
providers: [
  { provide: MaintainCOCService, useClass: MaintainCOCService },
  { provide: Configuration, useClass: Configuration },
  { provide: Router, useClass: MockRouter },
  { provide: ActivatedRoute, useClass: fakeActivatedRoute }
]
```

to

```
providers: [
  MaintainCOCService,
  Configuration,
  { provide: Router, useClass: MockRouter },
  { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: fakeActivatedRoute }
]
```